# discord.py SQLite database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord.py

So I am making a tag bot in discord.py with SQLite but I have a problem. This is the code so far:

```
sql.execute(f'select tag_name from tags_list where tag_name ={name}')
does_exist = sql.fetchone()

if does_exist is None:
    sql.execute('insert into tags_list(tags_name, tags_content) values(?,?)', (name, content))
    db.commit()
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Created tag with the name `{name}`")
else:
    await ctx.send(f"Tag named `{name}` already exists!")
```

The problem is that `does_exist` is meant to check if the tag already exists or not, but it doesn't. It doesn't do anything else either. This is how the table looks right now:

[image]

The code works without the if else statement. I can't figure the problem out, can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you've referred to the `tag_name` column by as `tags_name`

```
sql.execute(f'select tag_name from tags_list where tag_name ={name}')
#                    ^^^^^^^^                      ^^^^^^^^
does_exist = sql.fetchone()

if does_exist is None:
    sql.execute('insert into tags_list(tags_name, tags_content) values(?,?)', (name, content))
    #                                  ^^^^^^^^^
    db.commit()
    await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Created tag with the name `{name}`")
else:
    await ctx.send(f"Tag named `{name}` already exists!")
```

Please tell me if this works

**EDIT:**

So I created a test version based on your code and it works fine:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag_list (
             tag_name string NOT NULL,
             tag_content
             )""")

for i in range(0, 2):
    name = 'donut'
    content = 'choclate cream'
    print("Name:", name, "Content:", content)

    c.execute('select tag_name from tag_list where tag_name = ?', (name,))
    does_exist = c.fetchone()
    print("Exists?", does_exist)

    if does_exist is None:
        c.execute('insert into tag_list(tag_name, tag_content) values(?, ?)', (name, content))
        conn.commit()
        print('Created', name)
    else:
        print(name, 'already exists')
```

Output:

```
Name: donut Content: choclate cream
Exists? None
Created donut 

Name: donut Content: choclate cream
Exists? ('donut',)
donut already exists
```

I think the problem may be in this line:

```
sql.execute(f'select tag_name from tags_list where tag_name ={name}')

# Change it to

sql.execute('select tag_name from tags_list where tag_name =t', (name,))
```

That should work

Comment: i corrected the column names but it still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I think the part that is broken is the `sql.execute(f'select tag_name from tags_list where tag_name ={name}')` part